# Pushing indents before and after main body in typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm using React and Typescript, trying to do this:

```
    let indents: JSX.Element[] = [];
    indents.push(<div>);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        indents.push(<div>Testing</div>);
    }
    indents.push(</div>);
```

When indents.push(); is up top I get an error on the for loop.

My aim is to basically create the opening and closing tags at  the top level then add a bunch of nested tags before closing the top level tag.

Comment: JSX is not text. Consider opening and closing tags as parenthesis of function calls. I.e. `<div>Foo</div>` gets converted to `React.createElement('div', null, 'Foo')`. Hopefully this makes it clear why you cannot split opening and closing tags over multiple statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some thing like this:

```js
let indents: JSX.Element[] = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    indents.push(<div>Testing</div>);
}

return (
  <div>
    {indents}
  </div>
);
```

At the return statement you have to create react element `<div>` which will have children which actually will be your `indents`.

Comment: Yep this was the answer I was looking for. I had actually 'solved' the problem a different way before by wrapping the function in the div tags (namely <div>{this.myIndentsFunction()}</div>) but this resulted in odd rendering behaviour compared to the raw html. Your answers output replicates the html exactly.

I will mark this as the 'answer' in 2 minutes when stackoverflow lets me :)